# How were the quarter-millennium anniversaries of the resurrection of Jesus commemorated?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, history, easter, celebrations

I am wondering how the 2034 Easter celebration will look like from the perspective of various Christian churches. I am mostly interested in the Roman Catholics. Since we can only guess, I would like to ask about the past instead.

What were the 250th, 500th … 1000th … 1750th anniversaries like? Was there anything special, beyond the Masses and the gathering at that square at Rome and the usual "Urbi et Orbi" speech?

Comment: How are you so certain about the date?  And I thought the most common estimate was 33AD...

Comment: Well the RC church didn't exist yet in 250AD... so 500 would be the first one with the possibility of an answer.

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, the Church was suffering terrible persecutions around the time of that anniversary. (Decius' persecution took place around A.D. 250.)

Comment: @AthanasiusOfAlex Thanks for an useful observation. Another aspect is that maybe back then the quarter-millenium anniversaries were not seen as anything special. Did Early Christians Celebrate Birthdays?

Comment: @user7610 I am not sure about birthdays, but there are clear records of Christians celebrating Easter as early as the second century A.D. (St. Irenaeus of Lyon records that St. Polycarp visited Pope Sixtus I—around A.D. 120—to discuss a divergence of practice between the Church in Asia Minor and in Italy.)

Comment: I'm not aware of any commemoration of any kind for this sort of anniversary.

Comment: 1933 and 1983 were declared Holy Years marking the 1900th and 1950th anniversaries. This suggests any special celebrations will be in 2033 rather than2034, and may suggest a Holy Year will form part of the commemoration.

Comment: @jaredad7: Your history is very confused.